# How do you setup a Test View for your site in Universal Analytics?

Tags: universal-analytics

Someone on the Google Analytics Academy Community suggested that I setup a "Test View" for my site.  Where is that in Universal Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?  I don't think there is a feature with that exact name.

Testing can be done with "Experiments".  So maybe that is what you are after?

Most likely they want you to set up a View tho. Google heirarchy is like this: Account > Property > View.  Go to Admin tab and under view select "Create a new View".